# Flutter prevent editing input while on submit

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to know if its possible to disable the TextFormField while the data that was input is being submitted? This is to prevent editing the input while its submitting.

Comment: You can set the readOnly value to true while submitting. This will disable the editing in the TextFormField

Comment: Can you include your code snippet that will reproduce the same issue ? More about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by several ways using ignore pointer or TextForField's own property readOnly

1. Declare a variable on top of the class  like below:

   ```
   bool submitted = false;
   ```
2. Set your variable value to **true** while submitting your form.

   ```
   InkWell(
    onTap:(){
     setState((){
       submitted = true;
      });
     }
    child:Text("Submitted")
   );
   ```
3. Assign that value to your **TextFormField** or **TextField** like below:

   ```
   TextFormField(
    readOnly: submitted, //if true it will not allow user to edit else it will allow user to edit
    ...
   )
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Just create a loading animation to overlay the form while submitting